# How to detect when a particular date is reached?

Tags: javascript, date, events

I have a `Node.js` command-line application. When it is called, it enters an infinite while loop, which repeatedly asks for commands. During this process, I want to check when a particular `Date` is reached. It should not depend on the while loop or user input. I simply want the process to end when that `Date` is reached. Like an event:

```js
const date = new Date()

Date.on(equals(date), () => {
  // do stuff
})
```

Comment: you should consider using `cron job` https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron for performing these kind of process

Comment: Supposing that you have a way of converting the date to a Date object, then compare to 00:00 today, e.g. `if (date <= new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))` then it's on or before the start of "today".